# Autosave with Formik only when user has stopped typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have built an `AutoSave` component that submits a `formik` form when `formik` values change within the `formik` context.

### AutoSave.tsx

```
import { useEffect, FC, useCallback } from "react";
import { FormikValues, useFormikContext } from "formik";
import { omit, isEqual } from "lodash";

interface AutoSaveProps {
  delay?: number;
  onSubmit?: (v: FormikValues) => void;
}

const AutoSave: FC<AutoSaveProps> = ({ delay = 300, onSubmit }) => {
  const { values, errors, initialValues } = useFormikContext<FormikValues>();

  const isSameValueAsInitialValue = async (v: FormikValues) =>
    isEqual(v, initialValues);

  const onFormSubmit = useCallback(async () => {
    const v: FormikValues = omit(values, Object.keys(errors));
    if (onSubmit && !(await isSameValueAsInitialValue(v))) onSubmit(v);
  }, [values, initialValues, errors]);

  // add delay of 300ms by default, or whatever delay prop is
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => onFormSubmit(), delay);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [values, errors]);

  return null;
};

export default AutoSave;
```

I then have a simple input component that uses `formik` to update the inputs value with the `formik` context `onChange`

### TextInput.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useField, useFormikContext } from "formik";

interface TextInputProps {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  onChange?: (value: string | null) => void;
  onFocus?: () => void;
  type?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

const TextInput = (props: TextInputProps) => {
  const [field] = useField(props.name);

  const formikContext = useFormikContext();

  const onChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    formikContext.setFieldValue(field.name, e.currentTarget.value);
    if (props.onChange) props.onChange(e.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        {...field}
        {...props}
        onChange={onChange}
        style={{
          background: props.disabled ? "grey" : "initial",
          border: `1px solid ${props.disabled ? "red" : "black"}`
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextInput;
```

Then I have a `formik` Form that uses the `AutoSave` component to submit the form and the `TextInput` component as the field input for the form to trigger the `AutoSave` component.

### TestForm.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import TextInput from "./TextInput";
import AutoSave from "./AutoSave";

const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const TestForm = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ note: "" }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        console.log({ values });
        // simulate http request
        await delay(2000);

        return true;
      }}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting, submitForm }) => (
        <Form>
          <TextInput name="note" id="note" disabled={isSubmitting} />
          {isSubmitting && <p>SUBMITTING....</p>}
          <AutoSave onSubmit={submitForm} />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default TestForm;
```

So the issue that I have is that it currently triggers the auto save as the user is still typing. As the timeout gets set on the first change, and after it timesout, it attempts to submit.

Here's an example video, I am trying to type `123456789` into the input. I type `1` the timeout in `AutoSave` is triggered, I go to type `2` but the timeout has finished, so it submits, then disables the input until the submission has completed.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20436343/180211614-cdc24835-9203-4bbe-9af5-d9e114cdaad8.mov

I've had issues in my application where not disabling the input is causing a lot of issues, where the formik values seemingly get mixed up. see video below, I've typed `12345678` but what the field actually gets set to is `15678`

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20436343/180213292-00395e78-d26b-4928-aee8-21401a2a7f70.mov

I'm not sure a more refined way of doing this so that it only submits once a user has stopped typing/updating the form?

I have a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-wave-05lr4m?file=/src/TestForm.tsx) to replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `debounce` technique.

Classic one is something like this:

```
export function debounce(func, wait) {
  let timeout;
  return function (...args) {
    const context = this;
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeout = null;
      func.apply(context, args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

Usage: `const fnDebounced = useMemo(() => {return debounce(someFun, 400)}, [someFun])` and just bind it instead of someFun. But as you can see it is ok for void function due to no result is returned. So here is a slightly modified one that will return a promise in your case:

```
export function debounceAsync(func: any, waitMs: number) {
  let timeout: number = null!;

  return (...args: any) => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => resolve(func(...args)), waitMs);
    });
  };
}
```

And usage will be:

```
const TestForm = () => {
  const onSubmit = useCallback(async (values) => {
    console.log(values.note);
    // simulate http request
    await delay(2000);

    return true;
  }, []);

  const onSubmitDebounced = useMemo(() => {
    return debounceAsync(onSubmit, 400);
  }, [onSubmit]);

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{ note: "" }} onSubmit={onSubmitDebounced}>
      {({ isSubmitting, submitForm }) => (
        <Form>
          <TextInput name="note" id="note" disabled={isSubmitting} />
          {isSubmitting && <p>SUBMITTING....</p>}
          <AutoSave onSubmit={submitForm} />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit vigorous-lewin-jhk706]

Comment: is there any way to make it work smooth without disabling the input when the form is submitting or atleast refocus the input after saving